# umqtt.simple returning Error: [Errno 103] ECONNABORTED when publishing to mosquitto broker on windows 10

Tags: pi-pico, micropython, mqtt

**My problem:**
When attempting to send sensor data from Pico W using umqtt.simple to a Windows machine on my network running mosquitto, I can connect to the network but not to the mosquitto broker.  I get the error: Error: [Errno 103] ECONNABORTED

**My set-up:**
-Pico W using firmware: rp2-pico-w-20221219-unstable-v1.19.1-779-g57bb1e047.uf2
-umqtt version: micropythyon_umqtt.simple-1.3.4
-Windows 10 running mosquitto v2.0.15
-mosquitto config:
-per_listener_settings true
-listener 1883
-allow_anonymous false
-password file defined, with the password hashed
-Port 1883 opened on Windows Defender Firewall

**What I've tried:**
With this moquitto set up I've confirmed communications via command line:

1. start up mosquitto with my config file: mosquitto -c "c:\Program Files\mosquitto\mosquitto.conf" -v
2. listen for the topic: mosquitto_sub -u redacted -P redacted -t enviro/enviro-weather -d
3. publish to the topic: mosquitto_pub -u redacted -P redacted -t enviro/enviro-weather -m "hullo 7:17" -d

I've also successfully tested with MQTT Explorer on the same laptop.

**My code:**

```
import network
import time
import ubinascii
from secret import ssid, password
from machine import Pin
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient

def connect():
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        time.sleep(1)
    ip = wlan.ifconfig()[0]
    print(f'Connected on {ip}')
    return ip

sensor = Pin(16, Pin.IN)

#mosquitto settings
mqtt_server = "IP address redacted"
client_id = ubinascii.hexlify(machine.unique_id())
topic_pub = b"enviro/enviro-weather"
topic_msg = "hulloo"
user_t = 'redacted'
password_t = 'redacted'

def mqtt_connect():
    client = MQTTClient(client_id, mqtt_server, user=user_t, password=password_t, keepalive=60)
    client.connect()
    print('Connected to %s MQTT Broker'%(mqtt_server))
    return client

def reconnect():
    print('Failed to connect to the MQTT Broker. Reconnecting...')
    time.sleep(5)
    machine.reset()

try:
    ip = connect()
    client = mqtt_connect()
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: " + str(e))
    reconnect()
while True:
#    if sensor.value() == 0:
#        client.publish(topic_pub, topic_msg)
#        time.sleep(3)
    client.publish(topic_pub, topic_msg)
    time.sleep(3)
#    else:
#        pass
```

Code execution never gets to `print('Connected to %s MQTT Broker'%(mqtt_server))` and instead returns "Error: [Errno 103] ECONNABORTED" at line `print("Error: " + str(e))`

Comment: To me it is not clear if the error happens in `connect` or `mqtt_connect`. Does the code outputs anything at the line `print(f'Connected on {ip}')`? To troubleshoot would be better to see the full traceback of the error, so run the code without `try` statement - let it raise the exception and copy the output to the question above. In addition to that, check if your MQTT password or user name contain an escape character `\\` - should be avoided.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

I had no success using uqmtt.simple. I switched to uqmtt.robust and had no problems. This may have something to do with the comment on github about not working with CPython... unknown for sure.